# Why does TypeScript transpilation to target: ES5, Module: CommonJS cause errors in the browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules, es6-modules

I'm working with TypeScript and modules so that I can test with Jest. I am able to pass tests in Jest fine, but the transpiled JavaScript does not run in the browser. I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at scripts.js:2
```

The transpiled JavaScript is:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true }); // this is the offending line
var root = document.documentElement;
exports.root = root;
var button = document.querySelector('button');
if (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}
function handleClick() {
    if (root)
        console.log(root.style.backgroundColor);
    var color = '#000000'.replace(/0/g, function () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
    });
    if (root) {
        root.style.setProperty('--bg-color', color);
    }
}
exports.handleClick = handleClick;
var sum = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
exports.sum = sum;
```

As TypeScript declares that it "compiles to clean, simple JavaScript code which runs on any browser, in Node.js, or in any JavaScript engine that supports ECMAScript 3 (or newer)," I'm expecting this to run in Chrome.

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

I am deliberately trying to keep everything as bare bones as possible because I'm trying to learn some specific things about testing, environment set up, and node. It's possible I've gone too minimalist.

If I change the module to ES2015 the transpiled code works. Am I using CommonJS incorrectly? Is that meant to only run on a server?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The browser doesn't support exports without the module type `<script src="" type="module"></script>` and even then it isn't supported in all browsers.

Comment: You may need to instantiate a variable for `exports` by doing `const exports= {};` above `Object.defineProperty`

Comment: Add ```"lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],``` to compilerOptions

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, I have type="module" attribute on my script tag.

Comment: Browsers aren't supporting `exports` at all (supporting `export` though). It looks like you've configured the compiler to compile specifically for node.js.

Comment: @NSTuttle, This does work and there is a similar work-around doing the same thing but in a script tag in the html, but I'm trying to understand why the transpilations don't work, not so much hack around them.

Comment: @AliTorki, adding the "lib" property to the config doesn't work.

Comment: @Teemu, just to clarify that I understand you, CommonJS is a module syntax for Node. Since this app is meant to run in the browser, not a Node server, I need to configure transpilation to an ECMAScript module syntax. And since this module only exports, I'm not actually using the "moduleResolution" configuration (there are no other files or modules in this project.) Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with TS, but almost everything in that tsconfig refers to nodejs rather than browsers. Currently it looks like the browser is reading and executing the script. `exports` is not any kind of a native keyword or object in browsers, you've to create that object before referring it.

Comment: "moduleResolution": "node" does seem to be required in my case as the compiler needs to resolve modules from node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

The ES5 & ES6 & DOM libs should be included in your compilation.
To add these libraries, add **lib** property in **tsconfig.json**

```js
{
   "compilerOptions": {
     ...
     "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: the "lib" property isn't the issue this case. It's my not quite understanding when to target Node and when to target the browser, which is a big part of the reason for this study. The "lib" property may come into play at some point in this study, but I don't think I've hit it yet.